# twitteR authentication OAuth error in R

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

in R I am trying to use this code to connect to twitter.

```
library(httr)
library(twitteR)
library(rjson)
library(bit64)    

api_key <- "-redacted-"

api_secret <- "-redacted-"

access_token <- "-redacted-"

access_token_secret <- "-redacted-"

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

I get the error

```
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

having done a bit of searching I cannot resolve this, thank you for your help.

Comment: See [this thread](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/67). Says things are fixed with `httr 0.6.0` and `twitteR_1.1.8 `. What versions you are running? Show your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: sessionInfo() R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bit64_0.9-4    bit_1.1-12     rjson_0.2.15   httr_0.6.1     RCurl_1.95-4.5 bitops_1.0-6  
[7] ROAuth_0.9.5   twitteR_1.1.8

Comment: httr 0.6.1 twitteR_1.1.8

Comment: Well, i guess [this thread](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/74) re-opens the issue for 0.6.1. I might see if you can get help from the developer because apparently you are not the only person with this problem.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have figured it out.  My Asus X-series laptop has a problem with CMOS battery, in which the date and time are usually out of sync. When I am in correct date/time, however, authentication works as expected.  This is an issue with my system time, not R or OAuth, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

@tan dollars
This answer maybe pretty late, but 
I am pretty new to R and R Studio and analysis using twitter fata.

I have faced this issue in your question for weeks. Doing the below worked for me.

First install the packages httpuv httk httpRequest in R. Create a new app on apps.twitter.com. After saving the consumer secrets and keys, run the below line of code

> setup_twitter_oauth(your_consumer_key,your_consumer_secret,**access_token=NULL**,**access_secret=NULL**)

replacing the consumer key and and consumer secret with the respective values from your twitter app.

this should open a page in your browser asking for your permission. After you ok it, your authentication will be completed, following which you can access the tweets from the twitter api.

Hope it helps others facing similar issues.

Please make any corrections if necessary

Comment: thanks, in my case I discovered the issue was with the CMOS battery on my laptop, which affected proper timekeeping for my computer, which (I believe) affected communicating with Twitter and trying for authentication. I stopped experiencing the problem after I replace the CMOS battery.

Comment: Hi Tan. On an unrelated note, how did you determine it was the cmos issue?

Comment: it's been too long for me to remember exactly how but it came about while googling for hours and hours about authentication issues, and realizing I was having time-syncing issues with my laptop, my wife pointed out that she had time-syncing issues when her CMOS battery needed replacing. I had come across some posts corroborating the idea that I could be facing authentication issues because of the CMOS time issues (shortly after manual syncing I could authenticate, but once the clock got off, I could not, for example)